# newing up a complex object in a mvn plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm having trouble setting a default-value for a complex object in a maven plugin.

If I have a class called MyObject I would like to new it up by default, so I would like to do something like this in my Mojo:

```
/**
* Value class that wraps all report configuration.
*
* @parameter default-value="new MyCLass()"
*/
private MyClass classObject;
```

Now this is not valid, it doesn't create a new instance of MyClass by default (It compiles, but I get an error when trying to use the plugin).  I can put something into my mojo that news up classObject if it is null, but I would prefer to automatically do it using the @parameter annotation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer, actually very simple (and i'm kicking myself for not realising it sooner now):

```
/**
* Value class that wraps all report configuration.
*
* @parameter default-value="${classObject}"
*/
private MyClass classObject;
```

Just use the maven magic variable to set an instance of itself and it news it up for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Maven will allow you to set default value by calling constructor. So most probably, you'll have to check if object is null yourself.

I was only able to find this information on [mapping objects](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Complex_Objects). Check it out, it might be useful.

Comment: I've already gone through that, there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer either way.  I'm trying to find a definitive answer whether you can use the default attribute to new up a complex object or not.  Currently we are checking to see if the object is null or not and if it is we new it up but it just feels dirty